# Is it required that postgresql is installed on every client computers when retriveing or storing data?

Tags: c#, database, postgresql

I need your help to answer a question.
I coded a basic c# portable exe application that uses an Access Database on a server computer. On the network there are some client computers that runs this application and retrieve and store data via this database placed on the server computer in a shared folder. Every client coputer can access my database with this connection string:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =\\ANKFILESERVER1\aractakip\DatabaseAd.accdb
```

So far, there has been no problem. But as known, Access (Oledb) database has a limited capacity to save datas and since i'm worrying that someone change or delete my database files -authenticated for everyone- i decieded to use another database platform like postgresql. 
My question is, if i install postgresql on the server computer and migrate my database tables,  Are every client computers needed to install postgresql to access my database tables? If yes, what should be my connection string?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a client driver - like psqlODBC - installed on each computer that connects to PostgreSQL via MS Access, yes.

You can install psqlODBC separately, or using the main PostgreSQL installer. The separate psqlODBC-only installer is an msi that can be deployed over Active Directory, making management easier.

The connection options are covered in the psqlODBC documentation.

Microsoft Access is really written for the Microsoft JET / OLEDB engine, and to communicate with Microsoft SQL Server. It works with PostgreSQL, but it doesn't fully "understand" all PostgreSQL's features. It also does some things in totally non-SQL-standard ways that work on MS SQL but do not work on PostgreSQL. So it can be awkward to use MS Access with PostgreSQL due to things like Access not really supporting SEQUENCEs properly. Note, though, that I haven't used Access since Office 2008, so things may have improved.

Comment: No Craig, i don't necessarily need my old records to migrate, - however it makes my work easier- my main question is  whether client computers  can work in the  database on a certain server machine installed postgresql, even they don't have postgresql installed.

Comment: @Misto: You don't have to install the PostgreSQL database server on every client to let this client connect to some PostgreSQL server. Every client needs a driver, like psqlODBC, because client and server have to speak the same language.